# A simple proof that elementary equivalence and isomorphism coincide for finite structures?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm wondering if there's a straightforward proof of this result I've seen mentioned in quite a few places. If $\mathcal{L}$ is finite, of course, this is trivial since there's a single formula that defines the structure up to isomorphism. But what if $\mathcal{L}$ is infinite?

Comment: You can write down a formula that says "this structure has $n$ elements", for each finite number $n$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the two finite structures $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are elementarily equivalent, then they have the same cardinality. Now, there are just a finite number of bijections from $A$ to $B.$ Assume for a contradiction that none of those bijections is an isomorphism. For each bijection, choose an $\mathcal L$-relation which is not preserved. Consider the **finite** sublanguage $\mathcal L_0$ of $\mathcal L$ consisting of the chosen relations. Now, the $\mathcal L_0$-reducts of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are elementarily equivalent, and therefore isomorphic; but this is impossible because of the way $\mathcal L_0$ was chosen.

Comment: Doesn’t this imply that every bijection must be an isomorphism?

Comment: No. What makes you think it does?

Comment: After thinking for a while, I think I misunderstood the argument.  I thought the argument took a single (arbitrary) bijection which is not an isomorphism, and reached a contradiction.  I now understand -- I think -- that the correct version is "If any bijection is not an isomorphism in $\mathcal L$ then it is not an isomorphism in $\mathcal L_0$.  Therefore if the larger language has no isomorphisms then the smaller one has none.  But we know that the smaller one has some isomorphism."